# Using PHP Slim Framework

Tags: php

I want to use Slim for PHP in my project for the first time.
The manual says:

```
Install composer in your project:

curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
Create a composer.json file in your project root:

{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
Install via composer:

php composer.phar install
Add this line to your application’s index.php file:

<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I'm afraid, I don't get it. Where should the commands "curl" and "php" be used? I only access my webspace through Filezilla. How can I then apply such a command?

What do those steps do anyway? Sadly, the manual is not helpful at all.

Comment: Those commands assume you have terminal access to your webserver, either if you develop locally or through ssh for example.

Comment: My host is one.com. I guess they do not offer ssh access. Is there a workaround for those commands? Isn't "curl" just another fetch command for websites sources?

Comment: curl communicates HTTP and let's you fetch resources if you want to, but, it's piping the output of that URI to php, which means that you execute the code found on https://getcomposer.org/installer via php on your local machine. See my answer of what you probably want instead.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.slimframework.com/install:

> MANUAL INSTALL
>   Download and extract the Slim Framwork into your project directory and require it in your application’s index.php file. You’ll also need to register Slim’s autoloader.

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
```

And there are links to zip-files.

Comment: I saw this thank you. But it is not clear wether this is an "alternative" or if both steps are mandatory. I starting with this step you mentioned but ended up not being able to run the hello world on the very same manual.

Comment: What php version does one.com host? Tip: `phpinfo()`

Comment: 5.3.23 so sufficient for Slim.

Comment: I have a question maybe you buys will know the answer to but when i run these lines of code: \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(); it gives me a unexpected characer '\' in input and a syntax error for unexpected T string for the same lines.  any ideas?

Comment: @ShawnaMacNabb Perhaps you don't have a recent enough PHP version? (One that support namespaces.)

Comment: Namespaces were added in 5.3, perhaps you have 5.2.x or less.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting started on slim i'd definitely suggest that you get a good IDE that will guide you through the whole process. When I started the slim framework, I came across an IDE by jetbrains called PHPStorm. It makes everything so easy by doing most of the stuff you listed for you...

1. download and install PHPStorm https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/
2. download and install Composer https://getcomposer.org/download/ so PHPStorm can use it.
3. get to the part where you start PHPStorm.
4. go to File > new Project > Composer Project and follow the motions.

It'll create all the files you listed. Then all you have to do is look and learn what it all means.

Composer is basically a package manager, you basically open a cmd and navigate to the place you want to create you PHP Slim application and type some composer commands to install package files in that folder. Composer then gets the packages and puts them in a directory called 'vendor' in that project folder of yours.

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

that's basically a config file that either you or composer will create in the same file also.